# Move HTML (navigation) classes to top of container class with CSS?

Tags: html, css, navigationbar

I'm very new to HTML/CSS. On my navigation bar/header, I can't seem to get ".navleft " or ".navright" to move to the top of the ".container" class (My goal is to move the .nav classes to the top of the container so I can then center the text in their respective .nav classes, in turn centering them on the navigation bar). I've highlighted the space I'm talking about with white. When I use CSS to adjust their heights and margins, it only brings the section *down* on the page. I've also tried "top: 0;" in the two classes, which didn't seem to do anything.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 120px;
    background: #d0e5e2;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #000000;
    border-top: solid 4px #000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navleft {
    float: left;
    text-align: bottom;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.navright {
    float: right;
    text-align: bottom;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.navleft ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.navright ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.navleft li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.navright li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10vw;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
        <div class = "container">
            <div id = "logo"><a href = "index.html"><img src = "assets/bg1.jpg" width = 120 height = 120 alt = "Home" title = "Home"></a></div>
            <div class = "navleft">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class = "navright">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Move `<div id = "logo"><a href = "index.html"><img src = "assets/bg1.jpg" width = 120 height = 120 alt = "Home" title = "Home"></a></div>` under the navleft and navright divs

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will put the nav divs at the top of the container.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>

header {
    width: 100vw;
    height: 120px;
    background: #d0e5e2;
    border-bottom: solid 4px #000000;
    border-top: solid 4px #000000;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    margin: 15px 0 0 0; 
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 14pt;
}

#logo {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    text-align: center;
    margin: auto;
}

.container {
    width: 90vw;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

.navleft {
    float: left;
    text-align: bottom;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.navright {
    float: right;
    text-align: bottom;
    background: #ffffff;
}

.navleft ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.navright ul {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    top: 0;
}

.navleft li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-left: 10vw;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}

.navright li {
    display: inline-block;
    margin-right: 10vw;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<header>
        <div class = "container">
            <div class = "navleft">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">NEWS</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">PORTFOLIO</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class = "navright">
                <ul>
                    <li><a href = "#">ABOUT US</a></li>
                    <li><a href = "#">FAQ</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div id = "logo"><a href = "index.html"><img src = "assets/bg1.jpg" width = 120 height = 120 alt = "Home" title = "Home"></a></div>
        </div>
    </header>

</body>
</html>
```